# Removing lists from a list depending on the sum of the individual lists

Tags: python, list

I would like to remove from a list, lists depending on the sum of the list.  For example:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
import random


class Population:
    def __init__(self):
        self.population = []

    def random(self):
        for x in range(0,21):
            individual=random.sample(range(100),6)
            self.population.append(individual)
            print(self.population)

    def selection(self):        
        for individual in self.population:
            if sum(individual)<250:
                self.population.remove(individual)
                print(self.population)
```

I think that my code generates a list of 20 random lists.  I then want to select on this list and reject lists whose sum is less than 250.  I think the above code should work but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You should not mutate a list you are iterating over, either copy or use reversed. You will end up missing elements if you change the size of the list during iteration:

```
    for individual in reversed(self.population):
        if sum(individual) < 250:
            self.population.remove(individual)
```

Copying:

```
for individual in self.population[:]: # copy [:]
            if sum(individual) < 250:
                self.population.remove(individual)
```

Also `range(0,21)` creates 21 lists not 20, you want `range(20)`

Comment: Thanks!  That worked.  In addition how do I use 'copy'?  I tried copy(self.population) but it didn't seem to like it.  Do I need to import copy?  Thanks again!

Comment: @brighteyesburning007, No worries, copy is in the second example. reversed is probably more efficient though

Comment: @Padrian `list` doesn't have a `copy` :p

Comment: @JonClements, it sure does ;) Just not in python2, just saw the imports.

Comment: @Padrian not in Py 2.x... I'm going by the future imports and their comments the OP is using a 2.x version :p

Answer (score 0):

Re-write your function from:

```
def selection(self):        
    for individual in self.population:
        if sum(individual)<250:
            self.population.remove(individual)
            print(self.population)
```

To utilise a list-comp and in-place over-write your original retaining only valid items:

```
def selection(self):
    self.population[:] = [item for item in self.population if sum(item) >= 250]
    for item in self.population:
        print item
```

Comment: I think you mean `sum(item)` ;)

Comment: Thanks guys for all your help.  I may come back later with further questions!

Comment: @brighteyesburning007 feel free to make a separate question later... in the mean time - don't forget to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/204922) if you feel they helped you